# Wcf client and long-term operations

Tags: c#, wcf

Good day!

I have simple wcf service and desktop client,wich uses some functions.
But my client fault with exception that my wcf operation goes too long.

Some code:

```
 client=new MyWcfServiceClient();
 client.DoWork(param1,param2..etc);
```

I dont need to wait while DoWork do work. I need to execute this method and go forward. It is like send command to do some work and i dont need to get result immediately.

How to do that?
Thank you!

P.S. server side code looks like:

```
 DoWork(param1,etc)
   {
   // do long-term work at same thread
    }
```

P.P.S. i ingnore the result.

Comment: The problem can be fixed on the service side, using a background thread/task to do the work.  What does the service side code look like?

Comment: Sounds like a use-case for async operations.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx

Comment: Do you think,that if i will use Task at server code- this fix problem?

Comment: Yeah, but you may have other problems if you try to call the method multiple times.  I would normally put in some detection logic to see if its already running before starting a new Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along:

```
private static Task DoWork()
{
   // do stuff here
   // return something (?) assuming you need or care about this
}
```

and then you can do something like

```
Task task = DoWork().Start;   
// you can wait, poll, or if you don't care, ignore the result
```

Answer (score 2):

On the service, move your logic from: DoWork(param1, etc) to another method e.g. DoWorkBackground(...)

```
static Task _backgroundTask;

void DoWork(param1, etc)
{
    if (_backgroundTask == null || _backgroundTask.IsCompleted)
        _backgroundTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(
                                                () => DoWorkBackground(param1, etc) );
}

void DoWorkBackground(param1, etc)
{
    //long running logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET 4.5, you can create task-based proxies while adding service reference to an application. This can be done using by clicking on the Advanced button in the Add Service Reference dialogue. See [here](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/CallingWcfServicesAsynchronouslyUsingAsyncAndAwait.html) for more info.

Once this is done you will get the following: DoWorkAsync

Using this new proxy you can do things like this:

```
var result = await client.DoWorkAsync(param1,param2..etc);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify your DoWork operation, define it as OneWay, so it will return immediately. If DoWork is a web service, the HTTP code 202 will be returned.